# Splitting/Resizing a partition in GParted - got a key symbol next to the partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I was trying to free up some space on my ubuntu ext4 partition using GParted to install Windows 7. However, when I right-click the partition, most options to edit it are greyed out. There is a symbol of a key next to the partition name. There's about 29 GB free space on the partition. I am using ubuntu 13.04 and GParted 0.12.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **key** you see means that the partition is mounted.
Unmounting a running Ubuntu system is not possible.

Boot from the Ubuntu installation Live media.
Open GParted - no partition will be mounted.

In case you mounted a partition intentionally,
Right-click the partition and select Unmount.
Now you can work on the selected partition.

By the way, Ubuntu 13.04 isn't supported anymore.
You should use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS or 15.10 instead !